# undefined method `each' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

When I do rake db:migrate I get this error:

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for false:FalseClass
/home/chirag/social-login-in-rails/config/application.rb:25:in `<class:Application>'
/home/chirag/social-login-in-rails/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:SociaLoginRails>'
/home/chirag/social-login-in-rails/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chirag/social-login-in-rails/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/chirag/social-login-in-rails/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/chirag/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have cloned this app :- https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails

Comment: I didn't find the `social_keys.yml`, just find the `social_keys_example.yml`.

Comment: looks like you need to create `config/social_keys.yml` - there is an example profided in the config directory  ( `social_keys = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'social_keys.yml') `

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file 'social_keys_example.yml' to 'social_keys.yml' and put your app keys then restart the sever, it will work

Comment: ok it works fine when i did this but now when i click on login with facebook it gives me another error
undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Go through the following link hope it will help you [devise + omniauth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

Answer (score 0):

in config/application.rb

change

```
 social_keys = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'social_keys.yml')
```

to

```
social_keys = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'social_keys_example.yml')
```

Answer (score 0):

follow the instructions 
http://codebeerstartups.com/2013/10/social-login-integration-with-all-the-popular-social-networks-in-ruby-on-rails/

> In the config directory there is a file ie social_keys.yml. You need
>   to specify all the social keys there. Make sure have restarted the
>   application after making any change in that file.
>
> Here are the urls from where you can create an app and get the keys